# Get an array of 3 ordered values whilst favouring a specified value

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, design-patterns

Sorry for the somewhat generic title, if anyone has a better suggestion please let me know.

Basically I am writing a custom leaderboard view whereby I want to show 3 scores only.  If possible it will show the current user's score in the middle but, if the user is at the top or the bottom of the list, it should still show 3 scores but itll show another users above or below the list.

e.g.

1. Me (If I am top, then show 2 below)
2. User 1
3. User 2

or

1. User 1
2. Me (usual case where I am in the middle of two scores)
3. User 2

or

1. User 1
2. User 2
3. Me (If I am bottom show two scores above me)

I have a function written that does the first part of this but doesnt take into account edge cases which is what I am struggling with.  Can anyone please advise?

```
-(void)getNearbyScores:(int)score{
    GCLeaderboardScore *closestScoreAbove = nil; //Custom container for GC properties
    GCLeaderboardScore *closestScoreBelow = nil; //Contains playerID, score, alias etc

    if ([playerScores count] == 0){ //playerScores is an NSMutableDictionary
        return;
    }

    for (NSString* key in playerScores) {

        GCLeaderboardScore *playerScore = (GCLeaderboardScore *)[playerScores objectForKey:key];
        if ((closestScoreAbove == nil || closestScoreAbove->score > playerScore->score)  && playerScore->score > score){
            closestScoreAbove = playerScore;
        }
        else if ((closestScoreBelow == nil || closestScoreAbove->score < playerScore->score) && playerScore->score < score){
            closestScoreBelow = playerScore;
        }
    }

    me->score = score;
    me->rank = 1;
    if (closestScoreAbove != nil) {
        me->rank = closestScoreAbove->rank + 1;
        nearbyScores = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: closestScoreAbove, me, closestScoreBelow, nil];
    }
    else {
        nearbyScores = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: me, closestScoreBelow, nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a binary search tree it should be fairly easy to modify the "search" algorithm to do exactly what you need.

Comment: Instead of finding 1 score just above and 1 score just below, try to find 2 scores just above and 2 scores just below 'my score'.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I had thought of that but the problem is if I do this then there is a chance (I think) I won't find the second closest score unless I loop round twice, which I don't want to do

Comment: @Justin Not entirely sure how to implement that.. any chance of seeing some code (pseudo if need be)

Comment: @Chris if I have understood correctly you need not have to loop round twice for finding the second closest. Your if statements shall increase. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a `me` `GCLeaderboardScore` object, the method below should return an array with the desired `GCLeaderboardScore` objects (untested):

```
-(NSArray *)getNearbyScores {

    if(playerScores.count==0) return nil;

    // Create an array sorted by score
    NSArray *sortedByScore=[playerScores sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id object1, id object2) {
        GCLeaderboardScore  *score1=object1;
        GCLeaderboardScore  *score2=object2;

        if(score1->score < score2->score) return NSOrderedAscending;
        if(score1->score > score2->score) return NSOrderedDescending;

        return NSOrderedSame;
    }];

    // Find index of me
    NSUInteger  idx=[sortedByScore indexOfObject:me];

    // If me not found, return nil
    if(idx==NSNotFound) return nil;

    // Ideally we want to show the player before and behind
    idx=MAX(0,(NSInteger)idx-1);

    // maxIdx will be idx+2 or index of last object if lower
    NSUInteger  maxIdx=MIN(sortedByScore.count-1,idx+2);

    // In case we are last, show two previous results (if array large enough)
    if (maxIdx > 3)
                idx=MAX(0,maxIdx-3);

    // And return the objects, may be 1..3 objects
    return [sortedByScore subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(idx,maxIdx-idx+1)];
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty cool. My playerScores is a `NSMutableDictionary` though, can this be used in a similar fashion with that?

Comment: Works great apart from the last line, unsure what the issue is as I dont get an error per se.... `nearbyScores = [sortedByScore subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(idx, maxIdx - idx + 1)];`

Comment: Ah found it: ` Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray subarrayWithRange:]: range {4294967294, 4} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
`

Comment: @Chris Sorry for late feedback, glad you managed to sort it out!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an array of scores. (Actual implementation can be adapted to your code)

```
Initialize:  
firstScoreAbove = VERY_LARGE_SCORE; secondScoreAbove = VERY_LARGE_SCORE + 1;
firstScoreBelow = -1; secondScoreBelow = -2;

Scan the array elements.
if ( newScore > myScore ) {
  if ( newScore < firstScoreAbove ) {
     secondScoreAbove = firstScoreAbove;
     firstScoreAbove = newScore;
  } else if ( newScore < secondScoreAbove ) {
     secondScoreAbove = newScore;
  }
} else {
  // similarly for below.
}
```

After scanning,
If firstScoreAbove has not changed, then myScore is top and output the two below scores.
If firstScoreBelow has not changed, then myScore is lowest and output the two above scores.
Else Output firstScoreAbove, myScore, firstScoreBelow.

Comment: This is close but fails on edge cases I'm afraid

Comment: @Chris How does it fail for edge cases? I maybe committing an error but I'm sorry it's not clear.